# Preventing browser from commenting out php code html text editor

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor

I am using a html/javascript rich text area (CKeditor: http://ckeditor.com), that allows users to format text using html...  One feature is to wrap currently selected text in a `<code>` tag.  However, it seams that the browser is commenting out php code before the textarea is posted.

Example:
I enter the php code snippet:

```
<?php
echo "hello";
?>
```

Click on wrap code:
[image]

And expect as output:

```
<code>
<?php
echo "hello";
?>
</code>
```

However, what is inserted in the editor (by javascript) is:

```
<code><--?php echo "hello"; ?--></code>
```

Could this be a browser issue? (javascript causes the browser to render the html in the textarea of ckeditor, but the browser does not recognize the php tag?)

Comment: I think the problem is the same with any html tag. `<` and `>` are 'escaped' it seems, to allow only the editor to enter tag and not user. Perhaps it's customizable.

Comment: &lt;?php  //here your php code  ?&gt;

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CK Editor Documentation you must have the Code Snippet plug in enabled](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_codesnippet):

*The optional Code Snippet plugin allows you to insert rich code fragments and see a live preview with highlighted syntax. Its original implementation uses the highlight.js library, but the plugin exposes a convenient interface for hooking any other library, even a server-side one.*

You should then include PHP as a supported language.

[image]

Here is a link to the code snippet add-on: http://ckeditor.com/addon/codesnippet